# Migrar desarrollo de PHP5 a PHP7, principales diferencias

Tags: php

PHP7 es mucho más rápido que versiones anteriores e incorpora tipos de datos, pero... ¿cuál serían las principales diferencias? ¿qué deberíamos aprender primero cuando empezamos a desarrollar en PHP7?

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado por varios motivos: 1. Una eventual respuesta sería demasiado amplia; 2. Las respuestas dadas podrían estar basadas en «opiniones»; 3. No trata sobre un problema específico de programación; 4. No muestra lo que se ha investigado/intentando debido precisamente a lo dicho en los puntos 1,2 y 3.

Comment: Si en un sitio como este no dejan preguntar un poco los temas referidos a la programación, al final dejaremos de usar esta aplicación y buscaremos con "san google", ya que no servirá para nada este foro. Una cosa es que no se hable de temas que no son de programación, pero, ¿por qué no puede preguntar la gente cosas que están dentro de la finalidad de este foro? @Orici mirate esta pagina: https://www.php.net/manual/es/migration70.php

Comment: @CharlyUtrilla cualquier duda o problema que tengas con el funcionamiento del sitio debes expresarlo en meta y no en una respuesta a una pregunta. Lamentablemente he tenido que editarla dado que tu respuesta original no cabía como comentario, espero que la edición te parezca correcta. Por último, un enlace no es una respuesta en ningun caso.

Comment: @CharlyUtrilla ese es el problema, que este sitio no está pensando para ser un *foro*, sino para resolver problemas concretos que podrían servir también, claro está, como punto de referencia o aprendizaje. El problema de la pregunta es que no hay ningún punto de partida concreto desde el cual poder dar una respuesta concreta. Si tomamos por ejemplo esto: *¿qué deberíamos aprender primero cuando empezamos a desarrollar en PHP7?* ¿qué se puede responder? si eso depende de miles de factores, como, lo que cada uno conozca o no, lo que se requiera en ese contexto o no, etc...

Comment: @A.Cedano estoy un poco en duda entre si votar para cerrar o no, (1) es cierto que que la respuesta puede ser un poco amplia, (2) tal y como esta actualmente puede caer en opiniones, se podria acotar a versiones mas especificas ej 5.6->7.0, (3) para mi si es un problema relacionado con la programación, quizas es necesarior acotarlo un poco, (4) estoy deacuerdo en este punto. _¿qué deberíamos aprender primero cuando empezamos a desarrollar en PHP7?_ esta parte cae totalmente en opiniones.